# ASP.NET MVC 5 Model Navigation Properties Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have two models that I am trying to get working,

```
public class Contract
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string AwardId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Id")]
   public virtual ICollection<ContractHistory> contractHistory { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class ContractHistory
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string AwardId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Id")]
   public virtual Contract contract { get; set; }
}
```

There are many ContractHistory related to one Contract.

I keep getting a run-time InvalidCastException with that setup but when I remove the navigation property within the ContractHistory, and modify the Contract navigation property to:

```
public virtual ContractHistory contractHistory { get; set; }
```

It performs the join correctly without any errors.

I only have a year of experience working with .NET and at a lose as to what the issue could be. Ideally, I would like to navigate from Contract to a list of ContractHistory and from ContractHistory to one Contract. Worst case would be for me to create independent data repository methods to explicitly pull in these records but would prefer to figure out the solution to this problem for future reference.

Any advice or follow up questions are welcomed and thanks in advance!

Comment: In which line `InvalidCastException` was encountered? Your model seems look good, it may related to type cast problem between entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ContractHistory` class does not have a foreign key property.

Furthermore, you don't need to have the `ForeignKeyAttribute` overtop of `public virtual ICollection<ContractHistory> contractHistory { get; set; }` because you should be referencing the foreign key in the `ContractHistory` class.

The `ForeignKeyAttribute` constructor takes a string as a parameter.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Parameters
>
> name
>
> Type: System.String
>
> If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a foreign key property, you should specify the name of the associated navigation property. If you add the ForeigKey attribute to a navigation property, you should specify the name of the associated foreign key(s). If a navigation property has multiple foreign keys, use comma to separate the list of foreign key names.

So in your case:

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual Contract contract { get; set; }
```

You are placing the `ForeignKeyAttribute` on the navigation property, `contract`.  So essentially your class will search for a property called `Id` and identify that as the foreign key.  But in your class, `Id` has the `Key` attribute which means you are declaring that as your primary key.

So in order to resolve this, you need to add another property to your `ContractHistory` class that will be the foreign key.  And then change the string in your `ForeignKeyAttribute` to the name of that property.

Example:

```
public class ContractHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AwardId { get; set; }
    public int contractID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("contractID")]
    public virtual Contract contract { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, this is leading me down the right path but I want to clarify. The 'Id' property will be unique in the Contract table, but will have multiples in the ContractHistory table since there is a many to one relationship. You are saying to essentially duplicate that 'Id' property in the ContractHistory table and set it as the foreign key in order to join with the Contract model?

Comment: If that is the case, even though it is not needed I will modify the current 'Id' property within ContractHistory to be a true database generated field (key) and then create the additional 'ContractId' property and set it as the foreign key

Comment: @TheDirtyJenks that is correct.  Typically, if there is a 1-many relationship.. the Foreign Key will be in the 'many' table and that key will hold the unique value in the '1' table.  Therefore you can have `many` `ContractHistory`'s per '1' `Contract`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you want to implement one-to-many relationship, if so you have to remove the foreginkey attribute from the contract history collection in the contract class, and add contractId property as foreignkey in the contract history class as below:

```
public class Contract {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string AwardId { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ContractHistory> contractHistory { get; set; }
}

public class ContractHistory {
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public string AwardId { get; set; }

public int ContractId { get; set;}

[ForeignKey("ContractId")]
public virtual Contract contract { get; set; }
}
```